# Nav Mesh Agent and obstacles

Tags: unity, ai, navmesh

I have a scene with buildings and a Nav Mesh Agent. Should all the buildings contain the Nav Mesh Agent obstacle component, or them having colliders and being higher than agents step height is enough for the agent to avoid them at all times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stay with the collider and the height above the step height.

In the bake tab open the advanced options and change Min Region Area to a higher value and test it until the areas on your obstacles disappear.

Reference: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/nav-AdvancedSettings.html

Comment: Yeah I noticed their rooftops have walkabke areas :-) what do you mean by layer

Comment: Check out this for layers: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I am not sure if my approach works. I just realized that there is an other/easier way. I will edit my answer.